# How to access play configuration from a different module

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have a multi module sbt application, where one of the modules is a play application.

So my module layout is like:

/module1/
/module2/
/module-web    <-- this is play 2.x
/module3/

Now in my other modules I am using the typesafe configuration library (com.typesafe.config).

Now I have a module, module3, that will be used inside of my module-web (play) and it will also be used in another project.  I will synchronize the application.conf so it is the same in both the play project and in the other project.

My question is, how can I access the play application.conf from inside of module3?

module3 does not have the play framework as a dependency, just the typesaf config library.

I know play lets you do:

```
Play.current.configuration.getString("db.driver")
```

Is there something similiar but not using the `Play.current` method?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `ConfigFactory` class (most probably the [load](http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.html#load%28%29) method will fit your needs and you can also look at the parseString/parseFile methods), then call toConfig():

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import play.api.Configuration

val config = new Configuration(ConfigFactory.load())
config.getString("db.driver") ..etc
```